# VisualStudioコードスニペットで現在の日付を入力したい

Tags: visual-studio

タイトル通りですが、VisualStudioコードスニペットで現在の日付を入力したいと考えていますがやり方はありますでしょうか？

たとえば↓のような一行をスニペット文中に挿入したいのです。

例）// 2016/10/13 auther:dada

使用しているVisualStudioは2013と2015です。
ご存知の方がおられましたら是非ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [カスタマイズマクロ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890581/how-to-insert-current-date-or-a-specific-comment-assigned-to-any-shortcut-key-in)を作ることで実現できますよ。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
しかしカスタマイズマクロはVS2013以降機能が削除されているんです。

Comment: [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/)を利用して如何ですか。

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005～2015のコードスニペット中で[サポートされている関数](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms242312.aspx)は

- `GenerateSwitchCases` - switch-case文の生成
- `ClassName` - 現在の型名
- `SimpleTypeName` - 特定の型名の省略

の3個ですので無理だと思います。

Comment: pgrhoさんこんにちは。そうですか

Comment: 残念です。ご回答ありがとうございました。